# Pybind11 embedded module does not run when imported

Tags: python, c++, scripting, embedding, pybind11

I'm losing many many hours trying to the find the reason why my imported module does not work.

py_actor.cpp:

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include "py_actor.h"

namespace py = pybind11;

void Py_AddSpeed(double speed) 
{
    py_speed = speed;
}

PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(py_actor, m) {
    m.def("Py_AddSpeed", &Py_AddSpeed, "A function that adds speed to all actors");
}
```

test.py (In the same folder of the compiled `py_actor.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`):

```
from py_actor import Py_AddSpeed

speed = 16.0
print('UPDATING SPEEED!')
Py_AddSpeed(speed)
```

Somewhere in main:

```
py::scoped_interpreter guard{}; // start the interpreter and keep it alive
py::print("Hello, World! GZDoom now runs Python :)"); // use the Python API

py::module test = py::module::import("test");
```

Does the py::print work? Yes! Does the "Updating Speed" work? **No!** Why? I have no idea. I've recompiled the project like, a thousand times now and the imported module does not "run". I've even tried this:

```
py::exec(R"(
    import test
    print('Speeedd')
    print(test.speed)
)");
```

Nothing, no import errors, and no results either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what the problem was by doing

```
py::module test = py::module::import("test");
py::print(test.attr("__file__"));
```

It was then that I realized that there was a conflict with some internal module, and I renamed the module to "_test" and it worked. I hope this can save someone in the future.